# Zend Framework 2 Service Manager

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hello I have a problem and I'm not sure where my mistake is. I created a module named Phonebook and when I want to fetch the results from the database I get a blank page.

Here are my code examples:

Controller:

```
namespace Phonebook\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Phonebook\Model\Phonebook;

class PhonebookController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $phonebookTable;

    /**
     * Get Model Table
     */

    public function getPhonebookTableGateway()
    {
        if (!$this->phonebookTable){
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->phonebookTable = $sm->get('Phonebook\Model\PhonebookTable');
        }
        return $this->phonebookTable;
    }


    /**
     * Index Action
     * 
     * @see \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController::indexAction()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'phonebook' => $this->getPhonebookTableGateway()->fetchAll()
        ));
    }
```

**Note:** *I don't display the full source for the controller because it's so big.*

**Module.php Service Manager**

```
namespace Phonebook;


use Phonebook\Model\Phonebook;
use Phonebook\Model\PhonebookTable;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Phonebook\Model\PhonebookTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('PhonebookTableGateway');
                    $table = new PhonebookTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'PhonebookTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Phonebook());
                    return new TableGateway('phonebook', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

**PhonebookTable**

```
<?php
namespace Phonebook\Model;

// Get Zend Table Gateway

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;


class PhonebookTable
{
    protected $tableGateway; 

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @return Inject Dependency in TableGateway.
     */
    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all
     * 
     * Method fetch all article from database
     * 
     * @return resource
     */
    public function fetchAll() 
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

}
```

**Phonebook**

```
<?php
namespace Phonebook\Model;

class Phonebook
{
    /**
     * Item ID
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * First Name
     * @var str
     */
    public $firstname;
    /**
     * Last Name
     * @var str
     */
    public $lastname;
    /**
     * Phone
     * @var Str
     */
    public $phone;
    /**
     * City
     * @var str
     */
    public $city;

    /**
     * Exchange Data
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->first_name = (!empty($data['first_name'])) ? $data['first_name'] : null;
        $this->last_name = (!empty($data['last_name'])) ? $data['last_name']: null;
        $this->phone = (!empty($data['phone'])) ? $data['phone'] : null;
        $this->city = (!empty($data['city'])) ? $data['city'] : null;
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($phonebook as $item) :?>
        <tr> 
            <td> <?php echo $this->escapehtml($item->id);?>
            <td> <?php echo $this->escapehtml($item->firstname);?>
            <td> <?php echo $this->escapehtml($item->lastname);?>
            <td> <?php echo $this->escapehtml($item->phone);?>
            <td> <?php echo $this->escapehtml($item->city);?>
        </tr>   
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

When I remove the service manager from Controller, the page successfully renders without the database result.

Comment: In your view, what is the result of $phonebook->count()?

Comment: I dont see nothing just blanko white page. I have records in db table `phonebook`. Let me check `count` whitout feching result.

Comment: Ah again nothing is not render.:/

Comment: Last error what i get when i make is be: Cant get `Phonebook\Model\PhonebookTable` from service manager

Comment: hmm, are you overwriting getServiceConfig() anywhere else by chance?  Are you sure it is being called to set up your SM?  Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: Seeing an error is kinda impossible i'd guess. Just do hyper-professional `die("foo");` debugging. Test each line of your service factories and you'll find the error.

Comment: No i just have one SM in `Module.php` and get him in Controller `getPhonebookTableGateway()` just that i have. Application module and Phonebook module nothing else. Idk what is happen. I do this so many times and all time work good now idk whay this is happen

Comment: Page is rendered when i remove `getPhonebookTableGateway()`

Comment: Just making sure, public function getServiceConfig() is inside a class Module?

Comment: Just a second i set `APPLICATION_ENV` to `development` and i get Fatal Error `Fatal error: Class 'Phonebook\Model\Phonebook' not found in /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/module/Phonebook/Module.php on line `

Comment: @crowbird yes he is inside { } in class `getServiceConfig()`

Comment: This line causes Fatal Error : `$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Phonebook());`

Comment: I Slove problem. Problem be in directory for model. I write `model` i change to `Model` Deam i hate that

Comment: Ty guys for try help, realy

Answer (score 0):

you need phoneBook table; so in the controller you should have:

```
$phoneBookTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('PhonebookTable');

$allPhonebook=$phoneBookTable->fetchAll();
```